# Solar system datasets for exoplanet analogs?

Tags: solar-system, exoplanet, spectra, albedo

Are there data from the solar system available, that are about quantities we regularly investigate in exoplanet searches?

The only collection I know of comes from this paper: "[A Catalog of Spectra, Albedos, and Colors of Solar System Bodies for Exoplanet Comparison](https://www.liebertpub.com/doi/10.1089/ast.2017.1763)".

Comment: The key phrase here to look for would be "Earth as Exoplanet" or "Jupiter as Exoplanet" or "The solar system planets as exoplanets", there's a bunch of papers out there like that..

Comment: Whichproperties are you thinking of? Obviously masses, radii, semi-major axes etc are available for all the planets. Do you mean datasets (photometry, spectra etc.) that simulate observing the Solar System as if it were  a distant star system?

Comment: @ProfRob the latter.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape thanks! I'll have a look.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Unfortunately I did a good search both on google and in arxiv using these terms, but there is nothing.